# Hikvision MJPEG substream embed to HTML

Tags: camera, ip, hikvision

we're using a couple of hundreds Hikvision Cameras (DS-9664NI-I8) for a University. We want to embed them to a web page hosted locally. Cameras, NVR, and webpage are on same local network.

We don't want to use RSTP, we will use HTTP.

We're able to run the camera sub-stream on the browser using the following URL

```
http://<username>:<password>@<IP Address>/Streaming/channels/102/httpPreview
```

But, when I embed this to image src, this won't work, as browsers don't support the HTML embedded credentials.

How to play the camera streams on the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable security on streams. But if it possible - that depends on your camera and its firmware version. And be aware of consequences of course, secure your image with another means - firewall, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that too, but unfortunately, Hikvision firmware doesn't permit to do so.

Comment: @KamilSiddiqui If your cameras and application are on same local network there can be many workarounds. For instance, you can use small proxy service which will pass required credentials to cameras and return their stream without credentials. If you making your own surveilance app it can be just its function

Comment: Yes, right now we're using this approach, created an NGINX proxy web server and displaying the camera stream, the only issue is resources consumptions is very high.